# stateChangeSuccess after control is moved to next state controller in ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I have is a maze of `$state.go` and a lot of nested states. To simplify the problem, what I have is this.

**states.js**

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: "/create/",
    templateUrl: "/static/partials/hotel_offers/navigation.html",
    controller: "NavigatorController"
})
.state('main.photos', {
    url: "select_photos/:property_id/:template",
    templateUrl: "/static/partials/hotel_offers/photos.html",
    controller: "PhotoController"   
})
.state('main.details', {
    url: "offer_details/:reference/:property_id/:template",
    templateUrl: "/static/partials/hotel_offers/details.html",
    controller: "OfferDetailsController"
});
```

In **NavigatorController**,

```
$state.go('main.details', params);
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('dataFetchComplete');
});
```

When the code is in `main.photos` state.

In both **PhotoController** and **OfferDetailsController**,

```
$scope.$on('dataFetchComplete', function() {
    console.log($state.current.name);
});
```

The problem is I get `main.photos` in console which should not be the case. Basically what I need is an event that gets triggered when control is shifted to `OfferDetailsController`.

**UPDATE:**
It is not necessary to have the view or partial loaded. I just need an event when control is moved from one controller to other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
.state('main.details', {
    url: "offer_details/:reference/:property_id/:template",
    templateUrl: "/static/partials/hotel_offers/details.html",
    controller: "OfferDetailsController",
    onEnter: function(){
        do something...
    }
});
```

There's also an `onExit` callback for when you leave the view.

Comment: Definitely a solution but not what i'm looking for. As you can see, I need to broadcast an event on `stateChangeSuccess`. That, I don't think is possible via `onEnter`.

Comment: Using the onEnter callback is a cleaner way to do something on a state change, so try broadcasting with the rootScope `$rootScope.$broadcast('dataFetchComplete');` inside the onEnter instead of another function.

Comment: Found another way. Thanks for the response.